# Is it possible to use "best" without an article?

Tags: articles

Is it possible to use the word "best" without articles before of it? (the best quality, a best quality) For example in case of advertisement "best store around here!"

Comment: Note that advertisements will often omit articles as do newspaper headlines and signs (any place that space is limited). It's called "headlinese".

Comment: Sure. For example: [*best*](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/best): "2.  Best is the superlative of good. *James Fox is best known as the author of White Mischief.*"

Comment: Also in technical or scientific works: this is best practice